# nullpointerexception thread main exiting due to error

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Well the error is:

```
 W/dalvikvm(320): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.vosori.Amp$1.onCheckedChanged(Amp.java:58)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(ToggleButton.java:66)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:85)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:97)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)      E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 E/AndroidRuntime(320):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and.. source is :

```
public class Amp extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    WakeLock wL;
    public boolean tb;
    SeekBar volume;
    AudioManager am;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    AudioRecord arec;
    AudioTrack atrack;
    ToggleButton tbs;
    static final int buffersize = 200000;
    final short[] buffer = new short[buffersize];
    short[] readBuffer = new short[buffersize];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // wake-lock
        PowerManager pM = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wL = pM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        wL.acquire();
        // fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
            atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            atrack.setPlaybackRate(8000);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


            while (tb) {
                arec.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                atrack.write(readBuffer, 0, buffer.length);
            }

        tbs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbS);
        tbs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {
                    arec.startRecording();
                    atrack.play();
                } else {
                    arec.stop();
                    atrack.stop();

                }

            }
        });

        volume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb1);
        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int maxV = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int curV = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        volume.setMax(maxV);
        volume.setProgress(curV);
        volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Can you please help me? I'm stuck with this days, can't find way to fix this

updated
Edit: sorry D: i'm not that good with this D: i probably have a mistake here also
tried also to move those thing into oncheckedchanged method but didnt work :S

Comment: see line 58 in Amp.java?

Comment: line 58 is atrack.play(); but i dont really know what is wrong is that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing your arec and atrack variables until your method "run" is called.
I don't see anywhere in your code that you are calling the method run() so those variables will never get initialized.

Move initializing those variables into the onCreate and that problem should go away

Comment: you mean i have to move all the stuff inside method run into onCreate? deleted run method and copied all inside oncreate but it still has same problem :S can you explain more detailed please?

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code and I can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: updated :S probably i have done wrong sorry i'm not good at this D:

Comment: maybe you wanted to say that i have to put only arec.startrecording() and atrack.play() to oncreate method?  or can you say what do i have to do to call run method?

Comment: In order to use an object, you must first initialize it. You were not initializing your objects so they were empty/null (causing your null pointer exception). Your updated code should initialize your objects properly. Are you sure its still crashing for the same reason?

Comment: and.. while() i put that in onCreate too?